# SNR of a collection of waveforms follows the same distribution as an individual waveform

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, histogram

I'm generating some waveforms, produces by picking some $n$ samples from a Gaussian distribution. Not surprisingly, when I plot the sample values (i.e. a histogram with bins being the value of the waveform at that sample, and the vertical axis being *# of samples*) I see something that looks Gaussian.

Similarly, when I plot the SNR ratio for each sample in the same way (with noise value being the RMS of the waveform/Gaussian), I also see something that looks Gaussian.

What does surprise me, however, is what happens when I plot the SNR ratio for the collection of waveforms. I define the SNR of a single waveform (this time looking at whole waveforms as opposed to individual samples in a waveform) as the waveform's crest-factor divided by the RMS of the waveform (i.e., $\frac{max-min}{RMS}$ , where $max$ is the maximum sample value on the waveform, $min$ is the minimum sample value on the waveform). I find this value for all waveforms, and plot it on a histogram with the vertical axis being *# of waveforms* and the bins representing this SNR value.

Here, too, I see a Gaussian distribution.

I guess, since all waveforms are produced in the same way, I expected they'd all have more-or-less the same SNR ratio and, therefore, I'd see a nice sharp spike in this histogram. What's going on here?